# std::regex construct throw exception

Tags: regex, c++11

search line

> km.key.AB_ABCDEFG

I want to Extract 'AB'

I use `std::regex`

```
string pattern("^km\\.key\\.([A-Z]{2})_");    //this throw a exception

regex reg(pattern, std::regex::extended );
smatch sm;
if(regex_match(line,sm,reg))
{
    key_type = sm[1];
    return 0;   
}
```

But I am sure this regex is right.

`std::regex` is so hard to use?

Please help.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/11

Comment: @vks dot `.` has special meaning in regex pattern.

Comment: @user3218114 yes it does but it will not make any difference here.

Comment: @vks dot means any character but I want to match only dots. Will it check for dot only?

Comment: I know how to write the regex,  but it does not work in std::regex

Comment: Can't you at the very least specify which compiler you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look likes compiler bug (one mentioned for gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52719). Try on another compiler.

Another issue is with your regular expression - it must match entire string, [look at documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match):

> Note that **regex_match** will only successfully match a regular expression to an *entire* character sequence, whereas [std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) will successfully match subsequences.

This must work: `^km\\.key\\.([A-Z]{2})_.*`